# Trouble in passing ManyToMany Queryset data via Ajax call to django template

Tags: django, ajax, django-templates, many-to-many

I have two Models classes

```
 class Dishes(models.Model):
    dishName=models.CharField()

 class Hotels(models.Model):
    hotelname=models.CharField()
    dishes = models.ManyToManyField('Dishes')
```

In views.py

```
  def check_dishes(request):
    HotelId = request.GET.get('Id', None)
    hotelObj = Hotels.objects.get(pk=HotelId )
    dishesObj= hotelObj.dishes.all()
    data = {
    'HotelName': hotelObj.hotelname
    }
    Dlist=[]
    for dish in dishesObj:
       Dlist.append(dish.dishName)
    data.update([
        ('dishes_list', Dlist),
   ])
   print(data)
   *** output as below
   {'HotelName': 'DeMart', 'dishes_list': ['pizza','burger']}***
return JsonResponse(data,safe=False)
```

In hotels.html we have an ajax call like

```
 $("#getHotelDishes").keyup(function () {
  $.ajax({
     url: "{% url 'check_dishes' %}",
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {
        "hotelId": Id
     },
     // on success
     success: function (data) {
          {% for dishes in data.dishes_list%}
                //print dish Names of this Hotel
          {% endfor %}
     },
     // on error
      error: function (response) {
        console.log(response.responseJSON.errors)
      }
  })
```

});

Is this the right way to pass Queryset data via Ajax call,I could not get any result in for loop

Comment: Have you debugged what is the value of `data.dishes_list` in the ajax `success` function?

Comment: here `.GET.get('Id', None)..` Id should hotelId i.e : `request.GET.get('hotelId', None)`

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I was using template tags to iterator the list which is not working, I just deleted and updated the ajax function as below

```
  // on success
 success: function (data) {
    for (i = 0; i< data.dishes_list.length; i++) {
         //do something
    }
  },
```

But why is that the template tag failed to work,I still wonder!!